# Laravel Query Builder relationship plus no relationship

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I currently have this which works for querying a relationship:

```
$users = User::query();

$post_id = $request->input('post_id');

$users->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($post_id) {
    $query->where('id', $post_id);
});

return $users->get();
```

But in the results of this query I would also like to include Users that do **not have any posts connected to them**. So the result becomes: users without posts + users with a specific post (code above). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```php
$users->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($post_id) {
    $query->where('id', $post_id);
})->orDoesntHave('posts');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I'm still puzzled by query builder vs Eloquent. I thought I was using the former and could therefore not use the functions listed in the Eloquent docs. I actually posted another question because this didn't work: `$user->posts()->where('id', $post_id)` which according to the Eloquent docs should work.

Comment: How did it not work? Did you execute the query with `->get()`?

Comment: If I do `$users = User::query(); $users->posts()->where('id', $post_id); $users-get()` I get `Call to undefined method posts`.

Comment: What result should the query return? It only works on a single user instance: `User::find($id)->posts()->[...]->get()`

Comment: Ah right... The query should return an array of users so that's the issue. I find the docs (otherwise very good btw) in this query builder / Eloquent / what you can use and when quite confusing but this clarifies a lot, thanks!